# Compare root object value

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON list which has a two values `root object` name as a name and inside there a price. I have to compare the `root object name` with my variable called `marketName` and then grab the price there. What is the best way doing that? Here is my code at the moment:

```
foreach (JToken token2 in tokenJson2["response"])
{
    var name2 = token2[0];

    if(name2 == name)
    {
        // Do some fun here
    }
}
```

The JSON data comes from [here](https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetAllLowestListPrices/v1/?appid=730) ( I couldn't post it here, because it's too big)

Comment: You could use linq to simplify your expressions, otherwise a foreach loop should work as well.

Comment: How could I do the foreach loop? I can't find a way grabbing the item name from the list so I could compare it.

Comment: Is `tokenJson2` a `JObject`?

Comment: @JamesAniszt see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to iterate over the object and grab the one you want:

```
var item = tokenJson2["response"]
             .SingleOrDefault(x => ((JProperty) x).Name == name) as JProperty;

if (item == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Item not found.");
}

var price = item.Value["price"].ToObject<decimal>();
```

The confusing part here is that the endpoint is returning a property per item, instead of an array. Unfortunately you don't have any control over that :)

Comment: I don't think you need the `ToArray()` do you?

Comment: Thanks Sir, but it seems like for me it doesn't grab all the values/names only the first item?

Comment: @JamesAniszt Not sure what you mean by that. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Hello, you used a tokenJson2 there which means that it will only get the first item, but I have a foreach loop there as well. IF I replace  the tokenJson2 with that and remove that ['response'] then I get an error message.

Comment: I used the name `tokenJson2` from your example above. This is the root object that has the `response` property on it. Post your full code (including the part that calls the endpoint), it might clarify things up a bit.

Keep in mind that `tokenJson2["response"]` returns that object which includes multiple children, and `SingleOrDefault` iterates over them and grabs the only one whose name matches the one in your `name` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have multiple item names to compare with, so that's why I used a foreach loop as shown here: `foreach (JToken token2 in tokenJson2["response"])`

Comment: If you want multiple items returned, you can use `.Where()` instead of `.SingleOrDefault()` and specify as many conditions as you'd like.